# Not able to open DrawerNavigator tab inside stack-navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am not able to open the drawer navigator . Probably button is not getting navigation props passed to it .But i have no idea why is that happening .Drawer navigator is created inside stacknavigator so as it will display a hamburger menu on clicking the button on homescreen.

created a stacknavigator to navigate between screens Login,Signup,HomeScreen (HomeScreen in itself is a bottom navigation bar and home Component is being rendered as default in homescreen). A drawer Navigator is created to be opened on click (this button is part of Home ) but it's not opening with error "this2.props.navigation.dispatch not a function/object.

Here is my  Drawernavigator.js File

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {createAppContainer , createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import {View,Text,Image,TouchableOpacity,Button}  from 'react-native';

//importing customised components from other folders

import Home from '../components/Home';
import AboutPGMEE from './AboutPGMEE';
import FAQ from './FAQ';
import Settings from './Settings';
import ContactPGMEE from './ContactPGMEE';
import Notification from './Notifications';
import LogOut from './LogOut';
import TermsOfUse from '../Screens/InitialScreens/TermsOfUse';
import PrivacyPolicy from './PrivacyPolicy';
import ShareApp from './ShareApp';
import Videos from  '../components/Videos';
import AppContainer from '../FirstNavigator';
import HomeScreen from '../HomeScreen';
const DrawerStack=createDrawerNavigator(
    { 

/*

              HomeScreen:()=><HomeScreen/>,
   //() => <YOUR COMPONENT/> to suppress the error modifications made here into the syntax
     AboutPGMEE:()=>< AboutPGMEE/>,
     FAQ: ()=><FAQ/>,
      Settings:()=><Settings/>,
      ContactPGMEE:()=><ContactPGMEE/>,
      Notification:()=><Notification/>,
     LogOut:()=><LogOut/>,
      TermsOfUse:()=><TermsOfUse/>,
    PrivacyPolicy:()=><PrivacyPolicy/>,
    Home:()=><Home/>,

*/
    //   Home:Home,
        HomeScreen:FAQ,
       AboutPGMEE: AboutPGMEE,
       FAQ:FAQ,
      Settings:Settings,
      ContactPGMEE:ContactPGMEE,
      Notification:Notification,
      LogOut:LogOut,
      TermsOfUse:TermsOfUse,

    PrivacyPolicy:PrivacyPolicy

     },
     {
          initialRouteName:'HomeScreen',
           backBehavior:'initialRoute',
           drawerBackgroundColor:'powderblue',
           drawerPosition:'left',
           drawerWidth:300,
           contentOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
          },


     }

)

const SideBarNavigator=createAppContainer(DrawerStack);
 export default SideBarNavigator;
```

Below is my Firstnavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer,createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import LogInScreen from './Screens/InitialScreens/LogInScreen';
import SignUpScreen from './Screens/InitialScreens/SignUpScreen';
import TermsOfUse from './Screens/InitialScreens/TermsOfUse';
import Home from './components/Home';
import SideBarNavigator from './sidebar/DrawerNavigator'
const RootStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    LogInScreen: LogInScreen,
    HomeScreen: HomeScreen,
    SignUpScreen: SignUpScreen,
    TermsOfUse:TermsOfUse,
    Home:Home,
    SideBarNavigator:SideBarNavigator,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'LogInScreen',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default AppContainer;
```

below is my Home.js (only relevent code included . Larger file , assume syntax is fine )

```
import React from 'react';
import {Col, Row, Grid} from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import {View,StyleSheet,Text,ScrollView,Image,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Booklist from './BookList';
import {Card} from 'react-native-elements';
import {createStackNavigator,createAppContainer, DrawerActions} from 'react-navigation';
import SideBarNavigator from '../sidebar/DrawerNavigator';

export default class Home extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (  
  <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
  <View style={styles.container}>

           <View style={[styles.boxContainer,styles.bigheader]}>

                    <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column'}}>
                            <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column',backgroundColor:'#8E24AA'}}> 
                                             <View style={{backgroundColor:'#8E24AA'}}>
                                                  <Text>  </Text>

                                                 <View style={{flexDirection:'row',alignContent:'center',                  alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}> 
                                                      <View style={{flex:1}}>
                                                      <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}>

                                                      <Image source={require('./tab.png')} style={{height:30,width:35}}/>
                                                      </TouchableOpacity>

                                                      </View>
                                                       <View style={{flex:12}}>
                                                       <Text style={{fontSize:30,textAlign:'center',fontWeight:'bold',color:'white'}}>
                                                              DASHBOARD
                                                          </Text>

                  #########
                                     </View>
```

and this is HomeScreen.js

```
import  React  from 'react';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Qbank from './components/Qbank';
import Test from './components/Test';
import Videos from './components/Videos';

import { BottomNavigation } from 'react-native-paper';
//import AppContainers from './components/Home';

const GoToHome=()=>{
  return (<Home/>)
}
const GoToTest=()=>{
  return ( <Test/>)
}

const GoToQbank=()=>{
  return ( <Qbank/>)
}
const GoToVideos=()=>{
  return ( <Videos/>)
}



export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

 handleIndexChange=index=>this.setState({index});

 state={index:0,routes:[{key:'Home',title:'Home',icon:'home'},
                        {key:'Qbank',title:'Qbank',icon:'question-answer'},
                       {key:'Test',title:'Test',icon:'timer-off'},
                        {key:'Videos',title:'Videos',icon:"video-call"},
 ],};
renderScene=BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
  Home:GoToHome,
  Test:GoToTest,
  Qbank:GoToQbank,
  Videos:GoToVideos,

});

  render() {
    return (

     <BottomNavigation
  navigationState={this.state}
  onIndexChange={this.handleIndexChange}
  renderScene={this.renderScene}

       />


    )}
  }
```

I was expecting the drawer to be opened up on clicking image mentioned in Home.js. But it gives the error.

Comment: It is quite difficult to read your code, might I suggest formatting. However, just from the title, my guess would be it is because your drawer nav is nested in your stack. From my experience, this should be the other way around. The drawer nav needs to wrap the stack navigator.

Comment: @javenpoirier can you elaborate a little bit more . By wrapping stack navigator what you mean ? I can share the repo for that .... Can you suggest me some good docs for understanding this nesting and wrapping of navigators .

Comment: The best documentation would be react navigations: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html "You will need to make the drawer navigator the parent of any navigator where the drawer should be rendered on top of its UI."

Answer (score 0):

Example on drawer nav and nested nav stack:

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
    LogInScreen,
    SignUpScreen,
    TermsOfUse,
    DrawerNav
}, {
  ...
});

const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home,
    AboutPGMEE,
    FAQ,
    Settings,
    ContactPGMEE,
    Notification,
    LogOut,
    TermsOfUse,
    PrivacyPolicy
}, {
  ...
})
```

Home could then also be another stack navigator. You can also remove the component assignment if the name of the component is the same as the desired key.

Comment: I will definitely try that out . But since I am a newbie to react native so can you provide me with a solution?

Comment: I cannot give you a complete solution. I will edit my answer in your favor a bit. I can tell you that the reason you cannot call the dispatching of the opening drawer when the component that is calling it is not in the drawer nav. You need to move that Home component...

Comment: I tried to move the Home component in the drawer menu . But then I am getting error that "route component for Home should be a react component " as you can see . This is a reason why I have commented the Home component . Including "Home" or "HomeScreen " was producing same error ...

Comment: Tried the same . Not working .getting error  "undefined is not an object(Evaluating _this.props.navigation.dispatch)